# flutter web : get url of previous page that outside of my own web app

Tags: flutter

**Solution I seek for**

information about getting url of previous page that are outside of my own web app. *Ex. "google.com", "instagram.com"*

**Current issue**

I'm currently working on flutter web app which url will be shared on sns.
I would like page to be accessed only from instagram, hence seeking for the method to gain url of previous page to check.
But i can't seems to find any information regarding a matter.
I would appriciate any small information about package or method that can implement this.